# Analyzing server's HDD because it's getting full

Tags: hard-drive

my server is getting really full. It's just 10GB server and it's just have command-line. It has Ubuntu. Can anyone tell me any application which can analyze my HDD and find the largest files and folders.

The best would be if it just scanned server, generated a log and then I could check it and see the biggest folders and files.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [ncdu](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ncdu), it's available in the Ubuntu repo so

```
apt-get install ncdu
```

will install it if required. When you run it it will analyze the directory usage and present you with a sorted list that you can navigate.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/check-your-disk-usage-on-ubuntu-with-disk-usage-analyzer/

I found that when I was looking at disk usage -

Also Filelight has been around for awhile.

You can install from the source:

```
cd ~
wget http://methylblue.com/filelight/packages/filelight-1.0.tar.bz2
tar xjf filelight-1.0.tar.bz2
cd filelight-1.0
./configure --disable-debug && make
su -c 'make install'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could act like a real Linux user:). Without installing any extra tools, you can use **du** and **perl**.
The following command displays shows usage of each folder / file from smallest to largest on the box:

```
du -k | sort -n | perl -ne 'if ( /^(\d+)\s+(.*$)/){$l=log($1+.1);$m=int($l/log(1024)); printf  ("%6.1f\t%s\t%25s  %s\n",($1/(2**(10*$m))),(("K","M","G","T","P")[$m]),"*"x (1.5*$l),$2);}'
```